# Setting the height and width of a datagrid in .cs

Tags: silverlight-4.0

Could any one tell me the syntax for setting the height and width for a data grid in .cs?

Looking forward to a solution.

Thanks

prince

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataGrid1.Width = 100d